# SIO_LOOPBACK_FAST_PATH replacement?

Tags: windows, networking, loopback

Microsoft docs claim SIO_LOOPBACK_FAST_PATH is deprecated but do not point to any alternatives.  Google is not very helpful either.

Is there a replacement for it, or are we to use non-TCP based methods instead?

Answer (score 0):

As noted here [improving loopback throughput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/226455/improving-loopback-throughput):

**Jeffrey Tippet [MSFT]**

Feb 19, 2021, 1:39 PM

It's marked as "deprecated" for a few reasons:

- In recent OS versions, the normal, non-fast-path loopback has been
  improved quite a bit, such that SIO_LOOPBACK_FAST_PATH doesn't give
  as much benefit anymore.
- The option doesn't coexist with all other socket options, so there
  are some gotchas lurking there
- Not all WFP callout drivers support this option, so it may not
  interop well with other 3rd party software

We continue to work to make the loopback path fast, and the hope is that we can eventually make this socket option a no-op, since eventually the normal path will be just as fast as the "fast path".

All that being said, if you do measure a valuable perf benefit to using this flag (especially on older versions of the OS), you may certainly use it.